# Merge on left creates more rows than either DFs

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two dataframes. One is of calls, and one contains account info on a monthly basis. I have merged them together but am getting more rows than expected.

df1.shape is 134931,13   There were 134,931 phone calls in 2019

df.2 shape is 2845360,28  which is roughly equivalent to 254,329 customers receiving 12 bills in a year.

I'm using:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'left', on = ['acc_id', 'date'], indicator=True)
```

But df3.shape is 137912, 40
I would expect df.shape to be 134931,40

I checked the indicator column, and all rows were labelled as 'both'.

The dataframes look like:

````
```
df1
acc_id   date     call_length    call_time
1234     2019-01     01:09       2019-01-02 07:31:43.784
1234     2019-01     00:37       2019-01-31 17:03:46.326
7867     2019-01     02:01       2019-01-02 09:33:15.210
3456     2019-01     00:23       2019-01-08 10:18:05.410
3456     2019-02     00:12       2019-02-17 13:13:25.250

df2
acc_id  date     bill_amt       name
1234    2019-01   $4            John
1234    2019-02   $3            John
7867    2019-01   $2            Lisa
7867    2019-02   $4            Lisa
3456    2019-01   $1            Mark
3456    2019-02   $2            Mark
````

I've tried dropping duplicates. But this removes 0 rows.
I've checked and there are no Nulls in 'acc_id'.

As others have commented, if there are duplicate keys, merge will (as expected) create additional rows.

My new question, is therefore. How can merge DF1 and DF2 to achieve a DF3 that attaches the account name and bill amount from DF2 to each call[row] in DF2.

This is so that each call will have the associated account name and bill amount for later analysis. Is this even possible? I'm struggling to think of a logical way of doing this.

Comment: It's possible and **expected** if you have duplicated keys as shown in your sample data.

Comment: Fair point. But what is the best way to merge the two dfs to avoid this then? I do have another column that has more granular time. Should I delete this question and ask again but with additional columns in the df to open up options to other solutions. Or should I edit this question?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because when u merge both using left outer join tuples which have same [acc_id,date] values and differ in rest of the columns so they don't get identified as duplicates. As below:

```
df1
acc_id   date     call_length
1234     2019-01     01:09
1234     2019-01     00:37

df2
acc_id   date     call_length
1234     2019-01     04:39
1234     2019-01     06:57
```

on merging these both data frame the result in 4 rows. This might be the case that is why u are getting many rows than expected.

```
df3
acc_id   date     call_length
1234     2019-01     01:09
1234     2019-01     00:37
1234     2019-01     04:39
1234     2019-01     06:57
```